# Declaring a function in TypeScript that takes a derived version of a templated class

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a template class `Tmpl<A,B>`. I can extend this class just fine by saying `Derived extends Impl<string, string>`.

What I was is now to declare a function that takes in those derived class as an argument. Something like `f: (derived: T extends Impl<S,P>) => any`.

If I do `f: (derived: Impl)` it complains. I am not sure if this is possible but I know I am not going about it the right way.

Anything helps! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template parameters must come from somewhere. If you want to declare a function that could accept any Impl<> with any possible generic arguments, you can declare generic function like this:

```
class Impl<A, B> {
    a: A;
    b: B;
}

interface X {
    f: <A, B>(d: Impl<A, B>) => any;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This also helped with declaring functions too